# Why is dividing slower than bitshifting in C++?

Tags: c++, performance

I wrote two pieces of code, one that divides a random number by two, and one that bitshifts the same random number right once. As I understand it, this should produce the same result. However, when I time both pieces of code, I consistently get data saying that the shifting is faster. Why is that?

Shifting code:

```
double iterations = atoi(argv[1]) * 1000;
int result = 0;
cout << "Doing " << iterations << " iterations." << endl;
srand(31459);
for(int i=0;i<iterations;i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        result = result + (rand()>>1);
    }else{
        result = result - (rand()>>1);
    }
}
```

Dividing code:

```
double iterations = atoi(argv[1]) * 1000;
int result = 0;
cout << "Doing " << iterations << " iterations." << endl;
srand(31459);
for(int i=0;i<iterations;i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        result = result + (rand() / 2);
    }else{
        result = result - (rand() / 2);
    }
}
```

Timing and results:

```
$ time ./divide 1000000; time ./shift 1000000
Doing 1e+09 iterations.

real    0m12.291s
user    0m12.260s
sys     0m0.021s
Doing 1e+09 iterations.

real    0m12.091s
user    0m12.056s
sys     0m0.019s

$ time ./shift 1000000; time ./divide 1000000
Doing 1e+09 iterations.

real    0m12.083s
user    0m12.028s
sys     0m0.035s
Doing 1e+09 iterations.

real    0m12.198s
user    0m12.158s
sys     0m0.028s
```

Addtional information:

- I am not using any optimizations when compiling
- I am running this on a virtualized install of Fedora 20, kernal: 3.12.10-300.fc20.x86_64

Comment: Use optimizations. There is little point in profiling unoptimized code. Also, the differences are so small, I would run the comparison 100 times or so.

Comment: @juanchopanza I do use optimized production code. However, I'd still like to know why this difference appears. Also, I have run this comparison many times, with many different input sizes and found a similar disparity.

Comment: Then you should write some simpler code that does a division and a shift, and look at the assembly produced both with and without optimizations.

Comment: Did you learn long division at school? How long does it take for you to divide 484592 by 12545 vs. 484592 by 10000? Computers face essentially the same difference in the complexity. But without optimization, different divisors and looking at the assembly output you may not notice what really happens underneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't actually slower. I've run your benchmark using [nonius](https://github.com/rmartinho/nonius) like so:

```
#define NONIUS_RUNNER
#include "Nonius.h++"

#include <type_traits>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Divide", [](nonius::chronometer meter)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 9);

    std::vector<int> storage(meter.runs());
    meter.measure([&](int i) { storage[i] = storage[i] % 2 == 0 ? storage[i] - (dist(rd) >> 1) : storage[i] + (dist(rd) >> 1); });
})

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("std::string destruction", [](nonius::chronometer meter)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 9);

    std::vector<int> storage(meter.runs());
    meter.measure([&](int i) { storage[i] = storage[i] % 2 == 0 ? storage[i] - (dist(rd) / 2) : storage[i] + (dist(rd) / 2); });
})
```

And these are the results:
[image]

As you can see both of them are neck and neck.

(You can find the html output [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tm84g/))

P.S: It seems I forgot to rename the second test. My bad.

Comment: So I'm just getting very biased data. Huh. Well, thanks for the actual benchmarks (and the tool to do this better in the future)

Answer (score 3):

It's not; it's slower on the architecture you're running on. It's almost always slower because the hardware behind bit shifting is trivial, while division is a bit of a nightmare. In base 10, what's easier for you, 78358582354 >> 3 or 78358582354 / 85? Instructions *generally* take the same time to execute regardless of input, and in you case, it's the *compiler's* job to convert `/2` to `>>1`; the CPU just does as it's told.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that difference in resuls is bellow the results spread, so you cann't really tell if it is different. But in general division can't be done in single opperation, bit shift can, so  bit shift usualy should be faster.

But as you have literal 2 in your code, I would guess that compiler, even without optimizations produces identical code.

Comment: But it's obviously _not_ producing identical code.  If I run this comparison another 50 times, I still come out with a difference. The difference may not be significant, but it exists.

Comment: @Avery You haven't produced enough data for anyone to verify those claims. To me, your numbers look compatible with being "equal".

Answer (score 1):

Note that [rand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) returns `int` and divide `int` (signed by default) by 2 is not the same as shifting by 1. You can easily check generated asm and see the difference, or simply check resulting binary size:

```
> g++ -O3 boo.cpp -c -o boo # divide
> g++ -O3 foo.cpp -c -o foo # shift
> ls -la foo boo
... 4016 ... boo # divide
... 3984 ... foo # shift
```

Now add `static_cast` patch:

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
  result = result + (static_cast<unsigned>(rand())/2);
}
else {
  result = result - (static_cast<unsigned>(rand())/2);
}
```

and check the size again:

```
> g++ -O3 boo.cpp -c -o boo # divide
> g++ -O3 foo.cpp -c -o foo # shift
> ls -la foo boo
... 3984 ... boo # divide
... 3984 ... foo # shift
```

to be sure you can verify that generated asm in both binaries is the same